# Query from same table to extract different data

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

In a single table I have 3 columns. First defines a sector, second count and third amount. I need to extract 5 columns of data in the following manner. First column sector. Second and third to contains the values were amount is less than count and third and four to display were amount is more than count in the specific sectors. How should my query look?

Sample Data - 4 row data for sector one.

```
1,23,44 
1,20,15 
1,50,45 
1,30,20
```

Result should be

```
1,100,80,23,44
```

Comment: Can you show a sample data and desired result?

Comment: 1,23,44 1,20,15 1,50,45 1,30,20 - 4 row data for sector one . Result should be 1,100,80,23,44

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get it done using a `GROUP BY` and `SUM()` aggregate function along with `CASE` statement like

```
SELECT sector, 
SUM(case when count > amount then count else 0 end) as count1,
SUM(case when amount < count then amount else 0 end) as amount1,
SUM(case when count < amount then count else 0 end) as count2,
SUM(case when amount > count then amount else 0 end) as amount2
FROM mytable
GROUP BY sector;
```

Comment: Thanks.. Just had to modify it to the access syntax and viola, it worked!